# How to capture the client's IP within the model?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop

Consider the following code:

```
// common/models/test.js

module.exports = function(Test) {
    Test.observe('before save', function (ctx, next) {
        var x = <GET CLIENT IP> // <-----------
        next();
    });
};
```

How to capture the client's IP within the model?

Comment: And where is the module used, is there a `res` and a `req` parameter available etc ?

Comment: I don't know. I don't find in the documentation.

Comment: i don't really know anything about the frameworks you're using, but you have to have access to reponse and request objects coming from the client somehow ?

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know how to access the request object. :(

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to get request object from context using remote hooks. It is important to note that context object from operation hooks and remote hooks are different.

Check Operation hooks [docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Operation+hooks#Operationhooks-Operationhookcontextobject) and Remote hooks [docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks#Remotehooks-Contextobject) for more information.

```
module.exports = function(Test) {

  Test.beforeRemote('**', function (ctx, unused, next) {
    Test.ip = ctx.req.connection.remoteAddress;
    next();
  });

  Test.observe('before save', function (ctx, next) {
    if(Test.ip){
        console.log("IP: ", Test.ip);
    }
    next();
  });

};
```